# select2.jquery ajax,json search result not working i already checked for 4 hours and i ddidn't find any answers

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

i have a problem i tries to add jquery plugin select2 
i had select2.min.js to my html

here my html

my js

$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
        url: '/creditdebit/credit/association',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {

```
        var xdata = $.map(data, function (obj) {
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;  
            return obj;
        });

        $(".association").select2({
            placeholder: "test",
            data:xdata,
             search: data.term,

        });

    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        swal("Error ", request.responseJSON.message, "error");
        if(request.status == "401"){
            alert("Unauthorized Access ");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

});

the view:
[i cannot search the associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqzgW.png) 
my search does not working and its weird its not as the same place.

Comment: my html:                                         <select class="association"></select>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqzgW.png

Comment: i don't either why the input search is placed below????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="form-group rows">
  <div class="col-md-9">
<select  name="socNumber" id="mySelect" class="select2 form-control custom-select"  style="width: 100%; height:36px;>
<option value="" label="">
<c:forEach items="${associations}" var="assoc" >//from attribute in my controller
<option  value="${assoc.code}">${assoc.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
 $("#mySelect").select2({
         dir: "rtl",
})    
  });

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```